# If $a^{m}+1\mid a^{n}+1$ then prove that $m\mid n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

> Let $a$ be an integer, $a\ge2$. If $a^{m}+1\mid a^{n}+1$ then prove that $m\mid n$.

Actually I know a similar proof which is, $a^{m}-1\mid a^{n}-1 \iff m\mid n$, but I can't prove this. I also need some examples of the question.
Can't seem to find any correlation between the two proofs.
I seem to not find examples where $a$ is something different from $2$ and taking $m=2$.
Please help. I think 4-5 examples might help me to see the proof.

Comment: Specialize [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2983281/242) more general result on their gcd (but a direct proof is easier)

Comment: Note:  $3^3+1$ divides $3^9+1, 3^{15}+1, 3^{21}+1,...$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I see a pattern. Don't know if correct but I see it for $2^2+1,3^2+1,3^3+1,3^4+1$. That it is the third multiple,sixth multiple,ninth multiple of m which makes $a^n+1$ divisible by $a^m+1$. I guess it is correct for all primes . Thanks btw for it giving me little hint. Well seeing if I can find the proof or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose $\gcd(m,n)=d$. 
$$s=\gcd(a^{2m}-1,a^{2n}-1)=a^{2d}-1$$
But obviously $a^m+1\mid s$, so $$a^m+1\mid a^{2d}-1,$$ so $$m < 2d\Rightarrow d>\frac m2.$$ But $d\mid m$, so $d=m$ which means $m\mid n$.

Comment: Nice solution, the kind of I was looking after.

Comment: **Beware** that proving the first claimed gcd equality is where all the nontrivial work lies, and that is omitted above. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11567/242) for various proofs. One such proof is very smilar to the proof in my answer (which proves a stronger result).

Answer (score 1):

$U_{k} = a^{k} + 1$ are terms of a Lucas sequence; hence, $U_{m} | U_{n}$ iff $m | n$.

Comment: Can you attach an article about Lucas sequence? I can't find any about what you said.

Comment: Most of what I know about the Lucas sequences comes from D. H. Lehmer's "An Extended Throy of Lucas' Functions" published (1930) in the Annals of Mathematics. You should be able to access it with JSTOR or request it through interlibrary loan. I do not have an electronic copy.

Comment: Ok I will see .

Comment: $a^k+1=V_k(a+1,a),$ not $U_k.$ The *second* [Lucas sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence) $V$ do not enjoy the same nice divisibility properties as $U.$

Answer (score 0):

Theorem  $\,\Rightarrow\, c = \overbrace{a^{M}+1\mid a^{(M,N)}+1}^{\small\textstyle \Rightarrow \color{#90f}{M \le (M,N)}}\,\Rightarrow \color{#90f}{(M,N)= M}\Rightarrow M\mid N $

**Theorem** $\,\ \begin{align}c\mid a^M+1\\ c\mid a^N+1\end{align}\,$ $\Rightarrow\ \begin{align}&c\mid \color{#0a0}{a^{\large d}+1}\\ &\!d = {\small (M,N)}\end{align}\ \ $  **Proof** $\ $ Let $\,\begin{align} {\small M} &= dm\\ {\small  N} &=\, dn\end{align}\,\ $ so $\ (m,n)=1$

$\!\!\bmod c\!:\ a^{\large dm}\equiv -1\equiv a^{\large dn}\!\Rightarrow a^{\large 2d\color{darkorange}m}\equiv 1\equiv a^{\large 2d\color{darkorange}n}\,$ [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) $\,{\rm ord}\: a^{\large 2d}$ divides *coprimes* $\,\color{darkorange}{m,n}\,$ so it is $1,\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{a^{\large 2d}\equiv 1}.\,$ $\,(m,n)\!=\!1^{\phantom{I^{I^I}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\Rightarrow m\,$ or $\,n\,$ odd, wlog $\,n = 1\!+\!2j^{\phantom{I^I}\!\!\!\!}\,$ so $\ \color{#0a0}{{-}1}\equiv a^{\large dn}\!\equiv a^{\large d}(\color{#c00}{a^{\large 2d}})^{\large j}\!\equiv \color{#0a0}{a^{\large d}}$

Comment: The Theorem is excerpted from [this Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2983281/242) which computes the gcd $\,(a^M+1,a^N+1)\ \ $  More simply we could compute $\, a^N+1 \bmod a^M+1,\,$ but the Theorem is stronger and more insightful (and not much more work).

Comment: **Sigh**, serial political downvoter is still active (they always downvote my answer, then upvote the others - just as done $5$ mins ago here). The above proof is correct (and the easiest direct way). Both of the other answers use unproved results (whose  proofs are no shorter than above).

Comment: +1 but I find the logic of your post hard to follow (I am missing linking words; I guess what you mean only because I know it already). And imo the "easiest direct way" would be: let $n=mq+r$ with $0\le r<m,$ then $0\equiv(-1)^qa^r+1\bmod{a^m+1}$ hence $a^r=1.$

Comment: @Anne Thanks. I'm puzzled what logic is missing. The reason for presenting this method of proof is explained in my first comment above.