# Prove that if $a, m,n$ are positive integers with $a>1$ and $(a^m + 1) \mid (a^n + 1)$ then $m\mid n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can you show that if $a, m,$ and $n$ are positive integers with $a>1$ and $(a^m + 1)$ divides $(a^n + 1)$ then $m$ divides $n?$

I tried using modular arithmetic but I couldn't move further please help

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $a^{m}+1\mid a^{n}+1$ then prove that $m\mid n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229855/if-am1-mid-an1-then-prove-that-m-mid-n) (First hit [on Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a%5Em%2B1%5Cmid%20a%5En%2B1%24&p=1))