# $(a^m+b^m)\mid(a^n+b^n) \iff m\mid n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Prove  that $(a^m+b^m)\mid(a^n+b^n) \iff m\mid n$. Here $a, b, m, n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, $m\leq n$ and $(a, b)=1$.

This is a questions from a number theory book that I am recently studying.

I have read through the solutions of [$(a^m+1)\mid(a^n+1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3229855/if-am1-mid-an1-then-prove-that-m-mid-n) and [$(a^m-1)\mid(a^n-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413473/showing-that-an-1-mid-am-1-iff-n-mid-m). However, I wish to show the stronger statement of $(a^m+b^m)\mid(a^n+b^n)\iff m\mid n$.

My attempts:

When $n\geq 2m$, $(a^n+b^n)=(a^m+b^m)(a^{n-m}+b^{n-m})-a^mb^m(a^{n-2m}+b^{n-2m})$. Hence, $(a^m+b^m)\mid a^mb^m(a^{n-2m}+b^{n-2m})$. However, since $(a, b)=1$, $(a^m+b^m, a^mb^m)=1$, so $(a^m+b^m)\mid(a^{n-2m}+b^{n-2m})$ and we get another equation of the form $(a^m+b^m)\mid(a^n+b^n)$. We can repeat this process until $n<2m$.

Hence, suppose that $n<2m$. It suffices to prove that $n=m$. This is where I got stuck. How do I prove that $n=m$? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you guys find duplicates? I browsed 2 pages of Approach0 results and nothing came up.

Comment: FYI, I also initially used an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(a%5Em%2Bb%5Em)%5Cmid(a%5En%2Bb%5En)%5Ciff%20m%5Cmid%20n%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cgcd(a%2Cb)%3D1%24&p=3). Although this often works, I didn't see anything relevant in this case within the first $3$ pages. Instead, I found this by going to your linked [If $a^{m}+1\mid a^{n}+1$ then prove that $m\mid n$.](/q/3229855), where one of the RHS "Related" questions is [Proving that if $a^n+b^n \mid a^m+b^m$, then $n \mid m$](/q/3684683), with this being closed as a duplicate of the one I used here.